# How to Sync windows application between laptop and desktop

Tags: windows, sync

How to Sync windows application between laptop and desktop >

I have same configuration ( hardware and OS- e.g. windows 7 64 bit) on my desktop and laptop.
I want to know if there any sync tool which will sync windows application between multiple computers. like in my case laptop and desktop.(While exploring new application I tried to installed in on desktop/laptop and then again I have to do same installation with other machine.)

Please give some suggestion. preparing again new machine with all application is time consuming.

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't seem possible because of licensing restrictions.  A program will generally make it difficult to copy itself onto another system. Of course with free applications this is different.  If you have both application already installed and licensed on both systems, and you would like to synchronize the preferences that a different story.

Windows 8 will have an application store, and should provide this for you.  But in windows 7 this doesn't seem doable.

Windows 7 does not provide any native support for this, and because of the Windows registry this will be very complicated.

Answer (score 3):

If you install portable applications (for example, see [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/)), then you can use any type of file sync mechanism, such as [DropBox](http://db.tt/EPc2dMtU) (my personal favorite) to achieve this.  (Full disclosure: the DropBox link has my referral code; you are welcome to visit their site directly rather than clicking on the link.)

Answer (score 1):

If your apps are portable, you can use [Windows Live Mesh](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-essentials-other-programs?T1=t4) to do this.  Mesh allows you to sync a folder tree between multiple PCs.  I use this to run the same set of programs on my home PC and two work PCs - the sync happens automatically and in the background.

All Mesh files are also synced to SkyDrive, so both of your machines don't have to be on at the same time to allow the sync to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck with this using the Windows Setting and transfer wizard.  It copied over a fair number of the applications and settings from one PC to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox + http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html is great for keeping settings in sync between computers. Move the settings files to a Dropbox Folder an drop a Symlink in where they came from.